# SQL Average by TermID and yearID

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my SQL code contains tables: tblstudentdetail and tblstudentinfo

```
 SELECT distinct  TblstudentInfo.FirstName +''+ TblstudentInfo.LastName as Name,TblstudentInfo.StudentID, TblstudentInfo.YearID, TblstudentInfo.DualCredits, TblstudentInfo.DC_Classes, TblstudentInfo.DC_GPA, tblStudentDetail.StatusID, TblstudentInfo.ActScore,tblStudentDetail.YearID
      ,tblStudentDetail.TermID,tblStudentDetail.GPA
FROM TblstudentInfo

left join tblStudentDetail on TblstudentInfo.StudentID = tblStudentDetail.StudentID
order by  name
```

result:

```
Name StudentID  YearID  DualCredits DC_Classes  DC_GPA  StatusID    ActScore    YearID  TermID   GPA
Aaron   124             9   NULL        NULL     NULL     1            17        10     1      2.901
Aaron   124             9   NULL        NULL     NULL     1            17        10     2      3.171
Aaron   124             9   NULL        NULL     NULL     1            17        11     1      2.31
Aaron   124             9   NULL        NULL     NULL     1            17        11     2      3.31
Debbie  2344            7   NULL        NULL     NULL     1            19        9      1      4.31
Debbie  2344            7   NULL        NULL     NULL     1            19        10     1      4.31
```

How can I average avg the GPA? I want a result like this:

```
Aaron   124             9   NULL        NULL     NULL     1            17      2.923
Debbie  2344            7   NULL        NULL     NULL     1            19       4.31
```

Comment: DISTINCT has no useful purpose here nor in the accepted solution. So stop throwing it into any query that is not giving you what you want in an attempt to "solve" something. You include StatusID from the table that you are aggregating - be certain you understand what that column means and if/when it can vary for a given student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking to you result  You could use AVG() and group by

```
 SELECT distinct  
    TblstudentInfo.FirstName +''+ TblstudentInfo.LastName as Name
  , TblstudentInfo.StudentID
  , TblstudentInfo.YearID
  , TblstudentInfo.DualCredits
  , TblstudentInfo.DC_Classes
  , TblstudentInfo.DC_GPA
  , tblStudentDetail.StatusID
  , TblstudentInfo.ActScore
  , avg(tblStudentDetail.GPA)
FROM TblstudentInfo
LEFT JOIN tblStudentDetail ON TblstudentInfo.StudentID = tblStudentDetail.StudentID
GROUP BY TblstudentInfo.FirstName +''+ TblstudentInfo.LastName as Name
  , TblstudentInfo.StudentID
  , TblstudentInfo.YearID
  , TblstudentInfo.DualCredits
  , TblstudentInfo.DC_Classes
  , TblstudentInfo.DC_GPA
  , tblStudentDetail.StatusID
  , TblstudentInfo.ActScore
order by  name
```

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation:

```
 SELECT si.FirstName +''+ si.LastName as Name, si.StudentID,
        si.YearID, si.DualCredits, si.DC_Classes, 
        si.DC_GPA, si.StatusID, si.ActScore, si.YearID,
        AVG(d.GPA)
FROM TblstudentInfo si LEFT JOIN
     tblStudentDetail d
     ON si.StudentID = d.StudentID
GROUP BY si.FirstName, si.LastName, si.StudentID,
         si.YearID, si.DualCredits, si.DC_Classes, 
         si.DC_GPA, si.StatusID, si.ActScore, si.YearID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the AVG() function on the GPA and then Group by rest of the columns

```
SELECT si.FirstName +''+ si.LastName as Name, si.StudentID,
        si.YearID, si.DualCredits, si.DC_Classes, 
        si.DC_GPA, si.StatusID, si.ActScore, si.YearID,AVG(d.GPA)
FROM TblstudentInfo si LEFT JOIN tblStudentDetail d
ON si.StudentID = d.StudentID
GROUP BY si.FirstName, si.LastName, si.StudentID,si.YearID, si.DualCredits, si.DC_Classes, si.DC_GPA, si.StatusID, si.ActScore, si.YearID;
```

Comment: i think status id would be d.statusID